# WebView not visible on window

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview, visibility

I have a `WebView` that his `isShown` method return false even i set visibility `View.VISIBLE`... googling i found that view probably is not visible on window, i use this code to verify this, and in fact is not visible on window.

```
Rect scrollBounds = new Rect();
web.getHitRect(scrollBounds);
if (web.getLocalVisibleRect(scrollBounds))
{
   Log.d("STATE", "At least 1 px is visible");
}
else
{
   Log.d("STATE", "I completaly dissapear fool");
}
```

How can make the view visible on window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added the WebView to your view hierarchy? If you new it up

```
web = new WebView(...);
```

you need to add it to a parent view:

```
parent.addView(web);
```

or set it as the contents of your activity

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    web = new WebView(...);
    setContentView(web); 
}
```